# Unable to hide work item type in team explorer even after adding under hidden categrories in WI category file

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I have a team project which is migrated from VS2008 to VS/TFS 2012. In this team project, I need to hide two work item types - 'Shared Steps' and 'User Story' in Team explorer - [work items|New Work items] menu. I have added/defined this under the hidden category item in the WIT category file and imported the categories using witadmin command into team project. As a result 'Shared Steps' WIT got hidden but not the 'User Story' WIT which is still visible under new work items menu. How can I make 'User Story' WIT hide in this case?

Given below the xml portions that shows how I defined in WIT category file.

```
<?xml...

  <CATEGORY name="Requirement Category" refname="Microsoft.RequirementCategory">
    <DEFAULTWORKITEMTYPE name="User Story" />
  </CATEGORY>
......... 
  <CATEGORY name="Shared Step Category" refname="Microsoft.SharedStepCategory">
    <DEFAULTWORKITEMTYPE name="Shared Steps" />
  </CATEGORY>

.........

  <CATEGORY name="Hidden Types Category" refname="Microsoft.HiddenCategory">
    <DEFAULTWORKITEMTYPE name="Shared Steps" />    
    <WORKITEMTYPE name="User Story" />
  </CATEGORY>

........>
```

Any extra configuration in WIT categories or any other way out?

Thanks in advance!

/Jimmy

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug in Visual Studio. I tried doing the same thing in my local TFS instance and here are the results:

- Web Access doesn't have this problem, 'User Story' disappeared from the list as expected
- VS 2012/2013 however still shows the 'User Story' item in the menu but when I click it, it fails with 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.' exception

Comment: I also have the same problem in VS2013 Update 5.